# Polymer deep CSS

Tags: css, polymer

I am building a Polymer Single Page Interface with a lot of custom elements.

Now I want my elements to have some sort of master style, which I can define in the index.html or my main content element. Think of it like this:

**index.html**

```
<style>
    .classWhichWillBeUsedInCustomElements {
        mainColor: #e0e0e0;
    }
</style>
```

*or*

```
<script>
    mainColor = "#e0e0e0";
</script>
```

**my-cool-element.html**

```
<polymer-element name="my-cool-element">
    <template>
        <paper-button style="color: {{mainColor}}"></paper-button>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

*or*

```
<polymer-element name="my-cool-element">
    <template>
        <style>
            .coolButton {
                width: 300px;
                color: {{mainColor}};
            }
        </style>
        <paper-button class="coolButton"></paper-button>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Except that this doesn't work.

I have tried:

- Creating a global variable `window.defaultColor` and using it like `color: {{defaultColor}};`
- Using `core-style` in a parent element, without much luck
- Creating a css class in my `index.html` and calling it in a custom element

What is the right way to achieve this? I am trying to avoid using [Less](http://lesscss.org/)

Comment: I understand Polymer is a weird new library (heck, it's still in alpha), but I don't think it changes how you write your CSS. For example, styles still need to have a selector (like `paper-button {}`) and a style within them, like `paper-button { color: #e0e0e0; }`. Or you can just apply a class to your `paper-button` element and use that class as your CSS selector, instead of the `paper-button` element, itself.

Comment: I wrote that as a small example to show what I'm trying to achieve. I am aware of that not being valid CSS. As for using classes, that's not feasible. Since I want to use just the colour which is predefined, while still being able to use a class for my other attributes (e.g. width/height)

Comment: You can give elements multiple classes; `<paper-button class="first second third">` is valid and happens all the time. You can also combine inline styles with classes.

Comment: I tried that but when I write the css class in my `index.html` I can not use it in my custom element.

Comment: That might be because you're putting the CSS in `<style>` tags in your index.html file. Why not use an actually CSS file, and then you can just import it to any HTML file you want?

Comment: Well, that's the *oldschool* way. It is a possibility but I'm trying to achieve this the *Polymer* way. Using my elements where- and whenever I want without having to worry about adding an external css file to each and every element I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following pattern in the index.html or a global stylesheet:

```
<style>
    body /deep/ .classWhichWillBeUsedInCustomElements {
        mainColor: #e0e0e0;
    }
</style>
```

Then you could use the class within the custom element. The global style will punch the shadow boundary. You could replace body with any other element or selector under which you want to punch the shadow dom boundary.

More on deep here: https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/styling-elements.html#cat

Comment: Thanks! But this is close to being correct. I had to specify my main content element like this: `ap-content /deep/ .mainColor { background-color: #e0e0e0; }` and can now use that anywhere i specify `class="mainColor"`. Please edit in the correct order/use (`parent-element /deep/ className`) and I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: Also please add that `body /deep/ .mainColor` works as well and will result in all elements with `class="mainColor"` to use that css

Comment: updated. thanks for pointing out the inaccuracy of the response. did not had access to the code where got this working and memory did not served me well when answering ;)